# Почему при загрузке страницы на почту приходит несколько сообщений?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, база-данных, администрирование

Натянул сайт на Вордпресс. Там есть контактная форма, которая была подключена оnдельным файлом PHP.

Появилась проблема при натяжке - форма перестала работать. Не нашел никаких путей решения, только есть один плохой вариант.

Добавил такие строчки в functions.php - `<?php require_once('mail.php'); ?>`. Насколько я понимаю, это принудительный запуск на сайте. Вот и получается так, что он сразу запускается на сайте и на почту приходят пустые сообщения с форм обратной связи. Если я одну из этих форм связи заполняю, то сообщение поступает на почту, а вместе с ним и остальные пустые письма с незаполненных форм. Помогите запустить этот файл должным образом, чтоб отправка активировалась только при заполнении формы. Если нужна еще какая то информация для решения вопроса - я пришлю.

Comment: что добавлено в functions.php? почему не использовать cf7 для формы?

Comment: Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DarthKYL в functions.php добавил этот код <?php require_once('mail.php'); ?> Из за этого теперь письма приходят на почту, но постоянно, даже если не заполнять форму, а просто заходить на сайт. cf7 не использовал, так как изначально сайт не планировали запускать на WP.